# Automatic alignment between text below nodes in FlowChart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is my first TikZ diagram. I want to get the Figure like this

[image]

I use this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,rounded corners, fill=blue!20] at (2,1) (Start) {Some Text};
\node [draw,rounded corners, fill=blue!20] at (0,0) (Block1) {Text Text};
\node [draw,rounded corners, fill=blue!20] at (4,0) (Block2) {Text};
\node [draw,rounded corners, fill=blue!20] at (6,0) (Block3) {Text Text Text};
\node[text width=3cm] at (0,-1.5) {some text spanning three lines with automatic line breaks\\
Another line of text};
\path [line] (Start) -| (Block1);
\path [line] (Start) -| (Block2);
\path [line] (Start) -| (Block3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- Placement of node and related text below nodes.
- Equal distance between text below nodes.
- Make this diagram at Center of the page.

Edit: After getting the answer, I am wondering if I want the diagram as [image]

Comment: only omit middle node in answer's  MWE and eventually redefine `node distance`, for example to `node distance = 12mm and 0mm`. Of course, you need to define the branch coordinate, see addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326912/) to [a later question by Diaa Abidou](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326880/tikz-unequally-spaced-nodes) apparently answered this one possibly better, I am repeating that answer here for completeness. For a full explanation of the code, please [see the details I provided there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326912/).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  declare dimen register={gap},
  gap'=20mm,
  declare dimen register={lbox width},
  lbox width=(\textwidth-2*\forestregister{gap})/3,
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners},
  lbox/.style = {align/.wrap pgfmath arg={@{}p{##1 pt}@{}}{(lbox_width)}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={%
    font = \sffamily,
    edge = {draw, -{Latex}},
  },
  where n children=0{%
    lbox,
    no edge,
  }{%
    rbox,
  }
  [Some Text, name=Start, l sep+=5pt
    [Text Text, name=Block1
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
    [Text, name=Block2
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
    [Text Text Text, name=Block3
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned nodes in Forest tree]

## EDIT

In response to a query asking how to reduce the distance between the terminus nodes and their parents, I would change the value of `l` for those nodes. However, we need to delay this until after the tree is packed in order to override Forest's calculations.

For example,

```
  where n children=0{%
    lbox,
    no edge,
    before computing xy={%
      l'-=10pt,
    },
  }{%
    rbox,
  }
```

produces

[image: closer fit]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  declare dimen register={gap},
  gap'=20mm,
  declare dimen register={lbox width},
  lbox width=(\textwidth-2*\forestregister{gap})/3,
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners},
  lbox/.style = {align/.wrap pgfmath arg={@{}p{##1 pt}@{}}{(lbox_width)}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={%
    font = \sffamily,
    edge = {draw, -{Latex}},
  },
  where n children=0{%
    lbox,
    no edge,
    before computing xy={%
      l'-=10pt,
    },
  }{%
    rbox,
  }
  [Some Text, name=Start, l sep+=5pt
    [Text Text, name=Block1
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
    [Text, name=Block2
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
    [Text Text Text, name=Block3
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         font = \sffamily,
line/.style = {draw, -Latex},
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20, 
               rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
               node distance = 12mm and 18mm},
lbox/.style = {text width=32mm, inner sep=0pt,
               node distance = 2mm}
                        ]
\node (Start)   [rbox] {Some Text};
\node (Block1)  [rbox,below  left=of Start] {Text Text};
\node (Block2)  [rbox,below=of Start]       {Text};
\node (Block3)  [rbox,below right=of Start] {Text Text Text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block1] {some text spanning three lines 
                              with automatic line breaks.

                              Another line of text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block2] {some text spanning three lines
                              with automatic line breaks};
\node [lbox,below=of Block3] {some text spanning three lines
                              with automatic line breaks.};
\path [line] (Start) -- coordinate (a) (Block2);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block1);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my figure}
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I assume, that image is in document placed in float `figure`. Inside it you can center it with `\centering`. If this is not a case, then you can use

```
\begin{center}
< your tikz image >
\end{center}
```

In above MWE I defined styles `rbox` for rounded nodes and `lbox` for nodes below rounded boxes. For their positioning I use relative positioning from library `positioning`.

**Addendum:**
In case of image as show in edited question, you need to do some small changes:

- define coordinate `(a)` on the new way: `\draw (Start.south) -- ++ (0,-6mm) coordinate (a);`
- redefine `node distance` in `rbox` node style to something like `node distance = 12mm and 0mm`
- and, of course, delete `block` from code ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         font = \sffamily,
line/.style = {draw, -Latex},
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20,
               rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
               node distance = 12mm and 0mm},
lbox/.style = {text width=32mm, inner sep=0pt,
               node distance = 2mm}
                        ]
\node (Start)   [rbox] {Some Text};
\node (Block1)  [rbox,below  left=of Start] {Text Text};
\node (Block3)  [rbox,below right=of Start] {Text Text Text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block1] {some text spanning three lines
                              with automatic line breaks.

                              Another line of text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block3] {some text spanning three lines
                              with automatic line breaks.};
\draw        (Start.south) -- ++ (0,-6mm) coordinate (a);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block1);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my figure}
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but could you tell me how to parameterize the `lbox` width? For example, I need to define the spacing between the text nodes, then latex will automatically calculate each text node width based on the page geometry.

Comment: @Zarko, Nicely explained. I am wondering if I need only two boxes instead of three, then how do I change it? `\child` is not working here, maybe, I don't know how to use it with proper parameter.

Comment: This flowchart isn't draw with `tree`, so in it `child` is not employed. If you like to have image design on such a way,  then is worth to consider `forest` packages (with it I'm still very familiar). The width of `lbox` is deined with `text width` and it is set near value as you have in your MWE. It can be relatively determined in adance: 1/3 `\trextwidt` - 2/3 desired gap between them. To this width you can adopted `node distance` of `rbox` by trial :-). Some experience in drawing is very helpful in this.

Comment: @Torbjørn T., I wrote answer immediately after my lunch when I have more blood in stomach than in brain :-). Thank you very much for correcting my spelling and laguage errors.

Comment: @Zarko Now, it is clear about the  `lbox` width. Anyway, I added one new figure. Is it possible for you to provide the MWE?