# TikZ: How to make nodes equally spaced?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

Following this [question's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326870/2288), what is the reason behind this spacing inequality between the center text node and left/right ones in this MWE?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\gap{20mm}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         font = \sffamily,
line/.style = {draw, -Latex},
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20, 
               rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
               node distance = 18mm and 10mm},
lbox/.style = {draw=black,text width=(\textwidth-2*\gap)/3, inner sep=0pt,
               node distance = 5mm}
                        ]
\node (Start)   [rbox] {Some Text};
\node (Block1)  [rbox,below  left=of Start] {Text Text};
\node (Block2)  [rbox,below=of Start]       {Text};
\node (Block3)  [rbox,below right=of Start] {Text Text Text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block1] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\node [lbox,below=of Block2] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\node [lbox,below=of Block3] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\path [line] (Start) -- coordinate (a) (Block2);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block1);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my figure}
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `draw`. The nodes are spaced equally, I suspect. The text is always aligned left, though.

Comment: @cfr I updated the question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: discrepancy arise due to different `rbox` width. if you will write in the far let one the same text as it is in far right, you will get (amost) symmetrical layout. small differences is caused by left align of `lbox` content. See my answer.

Comment: @Zarko I copied/pasted the same text into the three nodes. Where to see your answer? here or the other question?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou, now it is here (below). I need some time to load-up all images, codes ... and today is Sunday in we suppose to rest not hard work .-)

Comment: @Zarko Many thanks for help. I hope I don't ruin your Sunday remaining free time :) It is already Monday here X)). Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes. I meant that it shows you that the nodes are skewed a bit left visually even when they are centred because the text is left-aligned rather than justified. (This isn't the only issue, I know, but `draw` can help diagnose at least part of what's going on.) Always draw boxes which don't align as you expect - nodes, `minipage`s, `\parbox`es, coffins, other boxes ... the lot. Boxes are TeX's thing, after all. (The stuff in the boxes is really incidental. TeX only cares about arranging boxes. Just a warehouse manager, really. No interest in the contents!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The asymmetry you can remove on many ways:

- define the same text width for `rbox`es, for example.:

  `rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20,
                  rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
                  text width=(\textwidth-2*\gap)/3,},`
- use grid for nodes placement without defining text width of `rbox`, for example:

  `\begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 18mm and \textwidth/3,
                   on grid,`
- etc

An example, which consider the first option with smaller text width than has `lbox` and centered text. Also in `lbox` add `align=justyfy` (which can cause ugly looks of text) or `align=center` (depends on what you more prefer). Result can be:

[image]

or

[image]

if in some `rbox` node in second level appear two (or more) line text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\gap{10mm}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and (\textwidth-9*\gap)/3,
%                on grid,
         font = \sffamily,
  line/.style = {draw, -Latex},
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20,
                 rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
                 text width=(\textwidth-4*\gap)/3, align=center},
  lbox/.style = {draw=black, text width=(\textwidth-2*\gap)/3, 
                 align=justify, node distance = 3mm}
                        ]
\node (Start)   [rbox] {Some Text};
\node (Block1)  [rbox,below  left=of Start] {Text Text};
\node (Block2)  [rbox,below=of Start]       {Text};
\node (Block3)  [rbox,below right=of Start] {Text Text Text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block1] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\node [lbox,below=of Block2] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\node [lbox,below=of Block3] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\path [line] (Start) -- coordinate (a) (Block2);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block1);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my figure}
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Considering second option with combination of the first one, you can obtain (this time with centered text in `lbox` nodes):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\gap{10mm}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 18mm and \textwidth/3,
                on grid,
         font = \sffamily,
  line/.style = {draw, -Latex},
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20,
                 rounded corners, inner sep=2mm,
                 text width=(\textwidth-6*\gap)/3, align=center},
  lbox/.style = {draw=black, text width=(\textwidth-2*\gap)/3, 
                 align=center, node distance = 12mm}
                        ]
\node (Start)   [rbox] {Some Text};
\node (Block1)  [rbox,below  left=of Start] {Text Text};
\node (Block2)  [rbox,below=of Start]       {Text};
\node (Block3)  [rbox,below right=of Start] {Text Text Text};
\node [lbox,below=of Block1] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\node [lbox,below=of Block2] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\node [lbox,below=of Block3] {1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1};
\path [line] (Start) -- coordinate (a) (Block2);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block1);
\path [line] (a) -| (Block3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{my figure}
    \label{fig-1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Too much typing :-). (+1) for working overtime.

Answer (score 10):

Since your diagram is a tree, may I recommend Forest? Forest is a Ti*k*Z-based package for drawing trees of which I am known to be rather fond ;).

Because the nodes of a Forest tree are tabulars, we can use `align[p{<dimension>}}` for the terminus nodes of the tree. This makes it easy to have left-aligned textual content with the node visually aligned at the centre, relative to its parent node above. This means it does not matter if the last line of the nodes is only partially full.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
```

We load the packages with the `edges` library which supports drawing the squared edges we need.

```
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

Now some set-up for our tree.

```
\forestset{%
```

We make `gap` a dimension `register`. However, you can stick to `\newlength\gap` etc. if preferred.

```
  declare dimen register={gap},
  gap'=20mm,
```

We'll need a dimension for the width of the terminus nodes. Actually, we don't strictly need it, but it seems convenient and efficient to do it this way.

```
  declare dimen register={lbox width},
```

We can use `pgfmath` to calculate the value of this dimension.

```
  lbox width=(\textwidth-2*\forestregister{gap})/3,
```

A simplified version of the `rbox` style from the MWE in the question. The other settings aren't really useful here.

```
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners},
```

And a redefined version of `lbox`.

```
  lbox/.style = {align/.wrap pgfmath arg={@{}p{##1 pt}@{}}{(lbox_width)}},
```

This basically tells Forest to get the value of the `lbox width` dimension register and use it in a `tabular` specification  for nodes with this style. We kill the extra spacing at the left and right of a `tabular` with `@{}` and use `lbox width` as the argument for a `p{}` column.

```
}
\begin{document}
```

Now for the tree. The first, optional part of a Forest tree is its *preamble*. This is everything up to the first (unprotected) `[`. The preamble can specify zero or more keys to customise the appearance of the tree.

```
\begin{forest}
```

For the squared edges, we just use the style from the library `edges`.

```
  forked edges,
```

We want some customisation to apply to the whole tree by default.

```
  for tree={%
    font = \sffamily,
    edge = {draw, -{Latex}},
```

This sets the style for the tree's edges so that they are drawn with arrows. (`draw` is default anyway, but this is clearer.)

```
  },
```

Now, we want a different style for the terminus nodes, which are the ones with no children, so we'll apply one style to those nodes and another to the rest.

```
  where n children=0{%
    lbox,
    no edge,
```

For the terminus nodes, we use the `lbox` style and `no edge` so the edges won't be drawn here at all, overriding our default.

```
  }{%
```

The rest just need `rbox`.

```
    rbox,
  }
```

That's the customisation. Now for the tree itself using the compact bracket syntax, starting with the root node.

```
  [Some Text, name=Start, l sep+=5pt
```

I've added `name`s for nodes corresponding to named nodes in the MWE. However, the example with Forest doesn't actually need them, so these may be omitted if they are not needed later in the diagram. `l sep+=5pt` adds `5pt` to the separation between the root and its children, because the default looked a bit cramped to me. Obviously this can be adjusted according to taste.

```
    [Text Text, name=Block1
```

The left-most child

```
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
```

and its child.

```
    ]
    [Text, name=Block2
```

The root's middle child

```
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and grandchild.

```
      ]
    ]
    [Text Text Text, name=Block3
```

The rightmost child

```
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and its child.

```
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

That's it for the tree. If we wanted, we could now add some regular Ti*k*Z commands here, using the node names specified, if needed. But we don't need that, so we just close the environment.

```
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest solution]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  declare dimen register={gap},
  gap'=20mm,
  declare dimen register={lbox width},
  lbox width=(\textwidth-2*\forestregister{gap})/3,
  rbox/.style = {draw=blue!80!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners},
  lbox/.style = {align/.wrap pgfmath arg={@{}p{##1 pt}@{}}{(lbox_width)}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={%
    font = \sffamily,
    edge = {draw, -{Latex}},
  },
  where n children=0{%
    lbox,
    no edge,
  }{%
    rbox,
  }
  [Some Text, name=Start, l sep+=5pt
    [Text Text, name=Block1
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
    [Text, name=Block2
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
    [Text Text Text, name=Block3
      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Equal space between texts below the nodes.

Comment: @Mithun I'm happy to have answered your question without your needing to ask it!

Comment: Many thanks, actually, I asked this question (see the link in the above question) Then, Diaa made a separate question with clear details. Anyway, from now, I will use TikZ for my work. Earlier I used VISIO and Inkscape.

Comment: I've posted the bare bones of this answer there as it possibly addresses your question better than this one. I wonder if I should delete this one and move everything there. I thought it answered this one, though. But I don't like duplicating answers. (If only because it looks like 'cheating'. But also because it is more annoying if stuff needs updating!)

Comment: @cfr Whenever you answer a TikZ question, you answer it as if you are writing  a PhD thesis :)) I appreciate the minor details you put in the answer which I will address back and forth later on.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou You mean I explain stuff? Sometimes ... ;)

Comment: @cfr I mean a lot, which puts a happy ending to any awful question :))

Comment: @cfr If you don't mind, I have one minor follow-up question about specifying different  children styles based on their levels. Can I ask it here by updating my question? or better ask a new one linked to this question?

Comment: @cfr One more request, how can we manage the gap between `rbox` and `lbox`?

Comment: @Mithun If you take a look at the [forest doc](http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf), you will find that the gap between the parent and its children is controlled by this `l sep` parameter. So, @cfr incremented this parameter in the root node by `5 pts` to increase the gap between it and its children. Same applies to other parent nodes that have texts of `Text`, `Text Text` and `Text Text Text`. I hope @cfr can confirm my answer is correct :) However, I don't know how to globally set this parameter instead of retyping it for every parent.

Comment: @Mithun I think I figured it out :) if you want to set the separation globally for all children, type `for children={l sep=20pt},` in the `forest` environment preamble, for example, beside `forked edges`. Don't forget the `comma` after the curly braces if it is not the last forest preamble option you set.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Thanks for the effort. Anyway, I want to reduce the gap between `lbox` and `rbox`, i.e, `[Text, name=Block2` and `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`. Same for all  spaces between`lbox` and `rbox` No global change. Another point, `for children={l sep=-5pt},` does not reduce the space.

Comment: @Mithun that's beyond my knowledge. I think cfr can help you with this stuff :)

Comment: @Mithun Please see edit in my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I think it would be better to ask a new question to avoid invalidating Zarko's answer to this one ;).

Comment: @cfr Can we reduce the vertical space between `Text` and `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` ?

Comment: @Mithun That's what my edit shows. Just check my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: @cfr I asked a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327014/2288), and I would be grateful if you could consider it.